# why user level threads need no system call?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I have read that the advantage of user-level threads is that they do not require kernel calls for switching. Does loading the registers (IP, SP) not require system call ? I programmed user-level threads in C using the functions - getcontext, setcontext ? Don't these function invoke system calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Most of) the registers visible to user-mode code can also be saved/restored in user-mode code.

Since a user-mode thread (at least normally) doesn't get switched preemptively, you don't normally need to save all the registers anyway. A typical implementation uses setjmp and longjmp to save/restore the necessary state. These typically don't involve any user/kernel mode switching.

Comment: I have a little doubt here. Does that mean that a user-level thread can load IP and SP to any value it likes without going through kernel?

Comment: More or less, yes. Loading into IP is just jumping to a location -- all the time you're executing code, you're loading values into IP all the time. More or less the same is true with SP -- every time you call or return from a function, you're loading it with a new value.

Comment: Does that mean that checking invalid addresses in these registers in not OS's concern?

Comment: No -- that's handled by the CPU. If you load an invalid address, the OS might get involved in handling the exception that gets raised.